# How to select result which calculates difference between two tables then display it along a third table?

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, difference

Regarding [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1gZBWOiH)

Table: `items`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bolt |
| 2 | wrench |
| 3 | hammer |

Table: `inwards`

| id | item_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 8.00 |

Table `outwards`

| id | item_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5.00 |

I want to `SELECT` table `items` with a third column `AS balance` which gets the difference between quantities (`inwards` - `outwards`)

My attempt:

```
SELECT it.* ,
(
(SELECT SUM(i.quantity)
FROM inwards AS i
WHERE i.item_id = it.id)
-
(SELECT SUM(o.quantity)
FROM outwards AS o
WHERE o.item_id = it.id)

) AS balance

FROM `items` AS it ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

The result I get:

| id | name | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bolt | 5.00 |
| 2 | wrench | null |
| 3 | hammer | null |

What I am aiming to get:

| id | name | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bolt | 5.00 |
| 2 | wrench | 8.00 |
| 3 | hammer | 0.00 |

Comment: You could use `COALESCE` as shown in the answer or you could alter your tables and make the column `balance` not nullable to avoid such "trouble". Just set the balance to 0 rather than `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have `coalesce()`ed your two sums which would prevent the nulls in the output. Check into null propagation to understand why that was happening. This can be fixed inside the subquery as `coalesce(sum(quantity), 0)`

You might also consider this approach which might give you better flexibility overall if other data columns become relevant:

```
with combined as (
    select item_id,  quantity from inwards union all
    select item_id, -quantity from outwards
)
select i.item_id, min(name) as name, coalesce(sum(quantity), 0) as balance
from items i left outer join combined c on c.item_id = i.item_id
group by i.item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Databases can't calculate with `NULL`, so you need to use something like `COALESCE` to check if the value is `NULL` and return a defualt valuze in your case 0

```
SELECT it.* ,
(
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(i.quantity)
FROM inwards AS i
WHERE i.item_id = it.id),0)
-
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(o.quantity)
FROM outwards AS o
WHERE o.item_id = it.id),0)

) AS balance

FROM `items` AS it ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

| id | name | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bolt | 5.00 |
| 2 | wrench | 8.00 |
| 3 | hammer | 0.00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HrKNdtvw)

Answer (score 0):

```
select it.*, ifnull(t.sum_quantity,0) as quantity
from items it
left join 
(
    select item_id,sum(quantity ) as sum_quantity from (
        select item_id, quantity from inwards
        union all 
        select item_id, -quantity as quantity from outwards
    ) u group by item_id
) t on it.id=t.item_id
```